# QML: running functions in parallel threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, qml

In my code I'm creating 16x16 buttons in cycle and this take few seconds.

```
onCreateField:
{
    for(var i=0;i<fieldWidth;i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<fieldHeight;j++)
        {
            createButton(i, j);
        }
    }
}

function createButton(x, y)
{
    __buttonX = x;
    __buttonY = y;

    __component = Qt.createComponent("GameButton.qml");

    if(__component != null)
        continueButtonCreation();
    else
        __component.ready.connect(continueButtonCreation);
}

function continueButtonCreation()
{
    var button = __component.createObject(field, {"row": __buttonY, "column": __buttonX});

     if (button == null) {
         // Error Handling
         console.log("Error creating object");

         return;
     }

     updateValveState.connect(button.stateUpdated);
     button.buttonClicked.connect(buttonClicked);

     field.clearField.connect(button.release);
}
```

While function that creating buttons runs, app freezes. I want to show loading animation while this function runs. So, how to run this function in parallel thread to avoid freezing?

Answer (score 10):

To do work in threads you have two possible approaches :

1. Read about the [WorkerScript](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-workerscript.html) element. It allows you to perform certain operation by running the javascript functions as threads.

**Note:** As given in the documentation, there is a restriction though :

> Since the WorkerScript.onMessage() function is run in a separate
>   thread, the JavaScript file is evaluated in a context separate from
>   the main QML engine. This means that unlike an ordinary JavaScript
>   file that is imported into QML, the script.js in the above example
>   cannot access the properties, methods or other attributes of the QML
>   item, nor can it access any context properties set on the QML object
>   through QDeclarativeContext. Additionally, there are restrictions on
>   the types of values that can be passed to and from the worker script.
>   See the sendMessage() documentation for details.

Just see, if for your particular use case it suits the requirement.

2
. Implement the functionality which are *heavy* as C++ threads. Whenever required, generate a signal to start this thread on the C++ side. When done, pass back the data from C++ to Qml , if required.

Answer (score 3):

As you may or may not have determined in other posts you cannot load QML objects in javascript in parallel.  Depending on your circumstances you should probably be using a GridView with a Delegate that renders a button.  This allows the underlying code to efficently render the buttons instead of sequentially creating them in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Other options to not block the UI might be

- use `incubateObject` instead of `createObject`
- don't create all Buttons within a single (16ms) frame: use a Timer to spread the creation of the Buttons over multiple frames